# MySQL or MongoDB for millions of rows sorted descending

Tags: mysql, mongodb

On each server I will have several customer databases with tables for user activity, account change logs, and a few others. Each table will have tens millions of rows added over the next year or so and into infinity.

For the case of user activity, all data will be read in descending order by time where the userID is X, but limited by about 10 at a time.

This seems reasonable, but for several tables in several databases, is this an OK approach? I worry that things will slow down quite a lot, especially as the tables grow for years to come. Should I split up the tables in some manner?

I'm wondering if MySQL InnoDB is the best way to store this data in each customer database. I was considering MongoDB however I keep reading that skip() gets very slow, and I can't find much details on sort then skip. Perhaps there's even another option.

Basically what would be the absolute fastest way to (store and then) read the latest pieces of information sorted descending by time? Obviously I'll do anything to make read time on viewing user information be as quick as possible.

Comment: why don't you group, list of 10 activities and form them a single document. This way the skip won't be that slow. And each query will be  at most single disk fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try both.

Simply put - there really isn't a *correct* answer here.  It will vary too largely by your requirements, your schema or document structure, your queries, your indexes, your hardware, your willingness (and availability of hardware) to shard, etc.

Both will work for what you want to achieve and each have their own solutions to these types of problems - example being: `foreign keys and joins vs embedded documents` or `sharding vs partitioning`.  When done correctly, both databases can work very well.

As you scale, your performance improvements are most likely going to include caching, pre-aggregating / pre-processing, mapreduce, etc - regardless of which Database back-end you choose.

#### Example with MongoDB:

It sounds like the most recent activities are the most viewed - this should mean that your working set should theoretically remain small even as your collections grow.  So, you could create a document per day per user with embedded documents for each activity.

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    user: 123,
    timestamp: 1370847600,
    activities: [
        { _id: ObjectId(...), type: 1, msg: "Something was logged.", date: IsoDate(...) },
        { _id: ObjectId(...), type: 2, msg: "Something else was logged.", date: IsoDate(...) },
        //More Activities here...
    ]
}
```

If you feel a day is not granular enough, or you feel your documents are too large - group by an hour.  This will help keep index size/working set reasonable and allow you to fetch multiple activities with out a join.

However, you also might find that you need more flexibility in querying just the activity logs by type or date - in which case embedding might not work as well.

Comment: I did this, but modified it to where I have a document that keeps track of the logs done by a user on which day, and then another document which stores user-day.

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of your MySQL? 
If it's 5.1 or later, did the table be partition? I think the partition by year may help, because you concerned about the tables grow for years.